# I want to :after and :before you to see the next and prev image

Tags: html, css

In my slideshow i have create :after and :before and i want the user to see the next and prev image.
Could some help me how to do this???

(I have a blur(10px) i want the background of blur to are the next and prev image)

Thanks a lot about your time.

[our html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i5i6.jpg)

```
.slideshow2 {
    position: relative;
}

.slideshow2 .slider {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}

.slideshow2::before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 6%;
    height: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    z-index: 2;
    border-right: 1.5px solid #fff;
}

.slideshow2::after {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    display: block;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    width: 6%;
    height: 100%;
    backdrop-filter: blur(10px);
    z-index: 2;
    border-left: 1.5px solid #fff;
}
```

Comment: share your code

Comment: just i share it!

Comment: Your HTML as well. Please make it a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Can you insert your HTML too as you did for CSS?

Comment: We don't write html...our cms create by default the pages etc we just change css